# After Plugin does not run at checkout

Tags: checkout, price, magento-2.2.5, plugin

Recently I create two **after plugins**, one that point to *Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Price\FinalPrice::getValue()* and other that point to *Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::getPrice()* and *Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::getFinalPrice()*

**etc/frontend/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
  <type name="Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Price\FinalPrice">
      <plugin disabled="false" name="morwifinalprice" sortOrder="99" type="Morwi\PrecioRegional\Plugin\FinalPrice"/>
  </type>
  <type name="Magento\Catalog\Model\Product">
      <plugin disabled="false" name="morwifinalprice" sortOrder="99" type="Morwi\PrecioRegional\Plugin\Price"/>
  </type>
</config>
```

**Plugin/FinalPrice.php**

```
<?php
namespace Morwi\PrecioRegional\Plugin;

class FinalPrice
{
    ...

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Price\FinalPrice $subject
     * @param float $result
     * @return float
     */
    public function afterGetValue(\Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Price\FinalPrice $subject, $result){

      ...

      return $result;
    }
}
?>
```

**Plugin/Price.php**

```
<?php
namespace Morwi\PrecioRegional\Plugin;

class Price
{
    ...

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $subject
     * @param float $result
     * @return float
     */
    public function afterGetPrice(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $subject, $result){
      ...

      return $result;
    }


    /**
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $subject
     * @param float $result
     * @return float
     */
    public function afterGetFinalPrice(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $subject, $result){

      ...

      return $result;
    }
}
?>
```

The plugins work fine and are executed without problem on all the site. Except on checkout. When I pass from cart to checkout, my plugins are ignored. I debugged and detected that the original methods are executed:

**Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Price\FinalPrice::getValue()**

**Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::getPrice()**

**Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::getFinalPrice()**

But the plugins not. Why is it? How can I run my plugins on checkout?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the problem. The plugin was defined only to **frontend** area. But, during the checkout process, the page made some request defined on **webapi_rest**. So, I copied **etc/frontend/di.xml** to **etc/webapi_rest/di.xml**, and it works.